# Getting complete URL for Selenium Automation using Python driver.current_url statement

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to get the complete URL from address bar of chrome. I am using this code.

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\ABC\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps');
#time.sleep(1) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('India Gate')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='searchbox-searchbutton']").click()
currentURL = driver.current_url
print(currentURL)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Instead of getting a complete URL in the address bar I am only getting `https://google.com/maps`

I need a URL like this `https://www.google.com/maps/place/India+Gate/@28.6337379,77.2060128,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x390ce2daa9eb4d0b:0x717971125923e5d!8m2!3d28.612912!4d77.2295097`

What am I missing? Please help. It's my first time using Selenium.

Comment: What happens if you add `time.sleep(5)` right after click on search button?

Comment: Right, I did that and now I am getting the complete location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your feedback on my comment I would suggest you the following code snippet:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\ABC\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps');
#time.sleep(1) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('India Gate')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='searchbox-searchbutton']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains("https://www.google.com/maps/place/")) # here you are waiting until url will match your output pattern
currentURL = driver.current_url
print(currentURL)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

***PS*** avoid as much as possible hardcoded pause

Comment: I remember you have provided great answers earlier implementing WebDriverWait :) why to fall back to `sleep ()` again?

Comment: Once you are a master, there shouldn't be any downgradation ;)

Comment: Why `time.sleep(5)` before `driver.quit()` ;)

Answer (score 2):

To extract the url you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `url_contains()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import re
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\ABC\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps');
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("India Gate")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='searchbox-searchbutton']").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.url_contains("Gate"))
  print(driver.current_url)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://www.google.com/maps/place/India+Gate/@28.6129167,77.227321,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x390ce2daa9eb4d0b:0x717971125923e5d!8m2!3d28.612912!4d77.2295097
  ```

---

### Update

As an alternative instead of `url_contains("Gate")` you can use `url_contains("data=")` as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains("data="))
```

Comment: hi, i am still getting the same response

Comment: @AMal Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: same response. I am using Jupyter. Do you think that might affect the output?

Comment: I tried changing the code to directly save the URL in a text file. There too I am only getting the shortened response and the not complete URL like you are getting at your console output.

Comment: @AMal Shouldn't have made any difference within Jupyter and save the URL in a text file as well.

Comment: @AMal I have increased the _Timeout_ now. Can you retest and update me with the status please?

Answer (score 1):

The same code block provided by [DebanjanB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb) worked when I increased the wait time.

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\ABC\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps');
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("India Gate")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='searchbox-searchbutton']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.url_contains("Gate"))
print(driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

This may be because your internet connection is slow or other factors.

Comment: It's still not working for me. Let me try in Firefox. Maybe it's a browser issue.