# Is there a way to scrape the page url (or a part of it) located in the address bar using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, imdb

I'm working on a huge dataset of movies and I'm trying to get the IMDb ID of each movie from the IMDB website. I'm using `selenium` in Python. I checked, but inside the movie page you can't find the IMDB code. It is contained into the link of the page, which is in the address bar and I don't know how to scrape it. Are there any methods of doing this?

This is an example of the page:

[image]

I need to get the underlined part of the url.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch the `title` of movie url you need to first fetch the `current_url` and then using python `split()` function you can get the second last string.

```
currenturl=driver.current_url.split("/")[-2]
print(currenturl)
```

This will returned `tt1877830`

Answer (score 1):

Try `driver.current_url`

Reference: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Also, worth noting that IMDB has an official API. You could look at that as well https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-bj74roaptgdpi?sr=0-1&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn’t know there was an IMDB API. I’ll definitely take a look.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the page url 9or a part of it i.e. the underlined part) e.g. ***tt1877830***, you can extract the [*current_url*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59623615/7429447) and split it with respect to the **`/`** character and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *Positive Index*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1877830/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.url_contains("title"))
  print(driver.current_url.split("/")[4])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  tt1877830
  ```
- Using *Negative Index*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1877830/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.url_contains("title"))
  print(driver.current_url.split("/")[-2])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  tt1877830
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```